# Desktop clean up function - Control, Command 1 – is not working after I installed Lion? Other keyboard shortcuts are working, as far as I can tell

Tags: macos, keyboard, desktop

What I thought was a universal keyboard shortcut (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) to cleanup and arrange my desktop, no longer works after I installed Lion. I can go up to the view drop down menu and click on it and it works but I like to use my commands. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard command appears to be <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to clean up by name now.